# How to Parse a Json Data Response from an API call in Ionic v3 and store in localStorage

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to access array data and store in localStorage.

I made an API call and get a response as below, shown on console

**My Api Provider:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:83/buildit/api';

@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  login(credentials) {
  //let headers = new Headers();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(apiUrl + '/login.php', JSON.stringify(credentials))
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res.json());

        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });

  }
}
```

**login.ts**

```
doLogin() {
     if(this.loginData.LoginID =='' || this.loginData.Password ==''){

     let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: "Enter username and password",
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'bottom',
      dismissOnPageChange: true
    });
    toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
    });
    toast.present();
     }
    else if(this.loginData.LoginID!=='' && this.loginData.Password!==''){
      this.showLoader();
      this.authService.login(this.loginData).then((result) => {
        this.data = result.data;
        console.log(this.data.loginStatus);

        if (this.data.loginStatus == 'Valid') {
          localStorage.setItem('loginStatus', this.data.loginStatus);
          localStorage.setItem('CustomerName', this.data.CustomerName);
          localStorage.setItem('Mobile', this.data.Mobile);
          localStorage.setItem('Email', this.data.Email);
          localStorage.setItem('CustomerID', this.data.CustomerID);
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(MyApp);
          this.loading.dismiss();
        }
        else if (result['msg'] == "Please verify your mobile no. to Login") {
          this.navCtrl.push(OtpPage,{
            ID : result['data'].CustomerID , Mobile : this.loginData.LoginID,
            Email: result['data'].Email
          });
          this.loading.dismiss();
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById('err-span').style.display = "block";
          this.loading.dismiss();
        }
      }, (err) => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.presentToast(err);
      });
    }

  }
```

Console.log(data) shows

[image]

```
{"data":[{
"loginStatus":"Valid",
"CustomerName":"Fagbemi Ayodele",
"Mobile":null,
"Email":"fagbemiayodele48@gmail.com",
"CustomerID":"3"
}]}
```

I need to parse the JSON data to get individual **'value'**

I tried `this.data.loginStatus` to get the **loginStatus** but it give null value, likewise for others.

Please, can someone show me how to get the data individual value in ionic 3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual values you can get like this:

```
data[0]['loginStatus']
localStorage.setItem('loginStatus', data[0]['loginStatus']);
localStorage.getItem('loginStatus');
//Valid

data[0]['CustomerName']
localStorage.setItem('CustomerName', data[0]['CustomerName']);
localStorage.getItem('CustomerName');
//Fagbemi Ayodele

data[0]['Mobile']
localStorage.setItem('Mobile', data[0]['Mobile']);
localStorage.getItem('Mobile');
//null

data[0]['Email']
localStorage.setItem('Email', data[0]['Email']);
localStorage.getItem('Email');
//fagbemiayodele48@gmail.com

data[0]['CustomerID']
localStorage.setItem('CustomerID', data[0]['CustomerID']);
localStorage.getItem('CustomerID');
//3
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir, I was able to solve it by converting **data** to array i.e **data: Array<any>;**